# Exporting SCNNode Data

Tags: swift

Just wondering, does Apple provided Swift SCNKit that allows user to quickly export out whatever 3D image currently being processed?

Let say if I am spawning bunch of 3D objects or particles, and then wanting to save a state of perhaps exporting the animation data out. Is this something that is easy to do?